# I need to find an excel formula that I can use to create a unique list of Item numbers from an array

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I need to find an excel formula that I can use to create a unique list of Item numbers from an array. I do not want to count them I just want to make a list of the Item Numbers. These part numbers are actually Alpha Numeric and can have repeating numbers through out the array multiple times. There is one other catch this list will have empty cells in it and could also be the first record in the array. This data is being pulled into Excel through a Jet report add-in for Excel.

Example: Starting in cell A1..A9

```
Item No.
<BLANK>
7810042050
783979
7810006045
7810006042
7810006032
<BLANK>
7810006022
7810006032
```

Comment: You want to dedup your list? This is built in excel functionality: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Copy the contents into the cells you want.  then use Remove Duplicates on the new column.  It is located in the Data tab.  Then find the one blank cell and delete it.

Comment: Here is the rest of the story that I did not think was important. I am building an automated report for purchasing. I want this so that no one has to do anything other than refresh the report, and email it out. The list needs to be dynamic each time the report is ran.

Comment: Then vba will be your best bet.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Do you know anyone that knows VBA? I am less than a newbie with VBA.

Comment: @Troy Since you are creating a report, perhaps a Pivot Table would be appropriate.  So far as VBA, as a start you could record your steps using the macro recorder; and for user ease, put a Button on the sheet which they would press to generate the report.

Answer (score 1):

With values in column **A**, in **C1** enter:

```
=MAX(A1:A10)
```

in **C2** enter the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A$1:A$10<C1,A$1:A$10,""))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

**EDIT#1:**

Chris Neilsen has pointed out that the values in column **A** are actually *Text* rather than *Numeric*.  To accommodate this, two changes must be made to the formulas:

- **A1** must be excluded
- the alphas must be converted to numeric.

So we will replace the normal formula:

```
=MAX(A1:A10)
```

with the array formula:

```
=MAX(--(A2:A10))
```

and replace:

```
=MAX(IF(A$1:A$10<C1,A$1:A$10,""))
```

with the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(--(A$2:A$10)<C1,--(A$2:A$10),""))
```

and then copy down.

Comment: This is beautiful!  :D

Comment: @Delta_zulu  Thank you.

Comment: Won't work for this Q.  From the OP _These part numbers are actually Alpha Numeric_

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I will try to adapt this to alphas.

Comment: @chrisneilsen  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

If you have alpha characters in the part numbers you can do this in 2 steps.

Both are array formulas and you need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Col B - sorted list of items in Col A

```
B2 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(COUNTA($A$2:A2),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,"<="&$A$2:$A$10),0),1),"")
```

Col C - eliminate the duplicates

```
C2 = IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $B$2:$B$10), 0)),"")
```

Copy both formulas down.

I tried to combine the two formulas but nesting an array (results in Col B) with varying row ranges did not work out. I could not find a way but the two formulas together will work.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this Formula Array in `B2` and copy to `B3:B10`

*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$10,
MATCH(1,1+COUNTIF($B1:$B$1,$A$2:$A$10)+(($A$2:$A$10="")*1),0)*1),"")
```

[image]